# How to get started with using Microsoft Immersive Reader SDK?

Tags: azure, immersive-reader

I wanna try using Microsoft Immersive Reader SDK using Node.js. I am following the steps listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/immersive-reader/quickstarts/client-libraries?pivots=programming-language-nodejs), which lists some **prerequisites** listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/immersive-reader/how-to-create-immersive-reader):

When I followed the steps listed at the previous link, and since this is the first time I am trying Azure, it prompted me to create a subscription. I did so. Then, I continued following the steps listed there, where **I got stuck when it asked me for the following parameters**:

```
-SubscriptionName '<SUBSCRIPTION_NAME>' `
  -ResourceName '<RESOURCE_NAME>' `
  -ResourceSubdomain '<RESOURCE_SUBDOMAIN>' `
  -ResourceSKU '<RESOURCE_SKU>' `
  -ResourceLocation '<RESOURCE_LOCATION>' `
  -ResourceGroupName '<RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>' `
  -ResourceGroupLocation '<RESOURCE_GROUP_LOCATION>' `
  -AADAppDisplayName '<AAD_APP_DISPLAY_NAME>' `
  -AADAppIdentifierUri '<AAD_APP_IDENTIFIER_URI>' `
  -AADAppClientSecret '<AAD_APP_CLIENT_SECRET>'
  -AADAppClientSecretExpiration '<AAD_APP_CLIENT_SECRET_EXPIRATION>'
```

**How can I continue as I have no idea on what to enter for all those parameters besides the SubscriptionName I guess? I know the page linked above gives you description of what these parameters are, but it doesn't tell me whether I create those parameter values on my own or do I retrieve it from somewhere in my Azure dashboard? Btw, I am just going to be developing locally for now.**

Also, I am using Cloud Shell in Azure to follow the steps listed on those links above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link you posted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/immersive-reader/how-to-create-immersive-reader) describes these parameters under step 3.

If you're creating a resource then you can you can choose the values for them on your own. If you already have an existing resource then you'll take the values from it.

So, resourceName will be the name of your Immersive Reader resource, e.g. "myImmersiveReaderResource" and so on so forth

Comment: Yes, I see that, but how do I know what to use for resourceName, resourceSubdomain, etc.? Are those values that I create on my own or am I supposed to retrieve them from my Azure dashboard somewhere?

Comment: If you're creating a resource then you can you can choose the values for them on your own. If you already have an existing resource then you'll take the values from it. So, resourceName will be the name of your Immersive Reader resource, e.g. "myImmersiveReaderResource" and so on so forth

Comment: What about the subdomain?

Comment: mySubdomain-1 or get creative

Answer (score 1):

After following some of the suggestions made by @Gama, I received "ResourceNotFoundError," meaning that there was no resource found under the "resource group" I had entered. So I had to click on the Resource group in my dashboard, and clikd on "Add" for adding a resource, then search for "Immersive Reader" and follow the prompts from there.